# radio buttons act like checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

Is it possible a radio buttons group to have the functionality like checkboxes? (possible jQuery solutions)

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you talking about unchecking radio buttons?

Comment: Check the "name" attribute, as Neil suggested.  This is basic HTML, and (probably) has nothing to do with javascript, let alone jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio buttons that contain the same name value will be mutually-exclusive.  If they all have separate name values you could play with the onclick event to set their state.